# how to monitor a windows service using a web page

Tags: asp.net, windows, service, monitoring

I have built a web page that does a complex processing, and I realized recently that I need to convert it to a windows service running at the background and keeping the web page for monitoring and initiating the service.

The service will process some files, and provides information messages to the user.

I'm not sure how to implement the link between the windows service and the web site, but i was trying to avoid using MSMQ to connect both application together.

what would be the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the service reference you can implement using Visual Studio, which provides you with an easy way to communicate with the service over HTTP.

WCF is a good service technology that integrates well with ASP.NET and different options for communicating with your site.

Comment: it is probably good idea to explore what can i do with WCF. Especially both applications are going to be deployed together on a single machine. Thanks for the idea